# How to debug Firestore Function onCreate()?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a Firebase Function with `onCreate()` function, which I would like to debug. My goal is, that when I add a new element in the Firebase Database, to stop the app at the breakpoint in the `onCreate()` function.

I tried to follow [these](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/debugging-firebase-functions-in-vs-code-a1caf22db0b2) steps but it's not working.

```
export const buySellSignal = functions.database.ref("/users/{userId}/signals/{signalId}")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const signal = snapshot.val();

    if (signal.type == "Buy") {
      buy(signal.pair, signal.userId);
    } else {
      sell(signal.pair, signal.userId);
    }

    database.ref(`users/${context.params.userId}/signals/${context.params.signalId}`).remove();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the port is correct? The article says 9229 but according to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#port_configuration) the default port for functions is 5001

Comment: if I change to 5001, it won't start when I click on 'Run'

Comment: If you followed some steps, you should repeat them here in your post so we can follow along with your steps specifically. If you find an error or other unexpected behavior, your post should include that too so we can see what went wrong.  "It's not working" isn't enough information to know how to help you.